# How to compare all elements of vector one to vector two and if a max element exists then comparing all the elements of vector two to vector three?

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, compare

I want to compare all element of vector x to all elements of vector y and if I find a element greater in vector y than being compared to, I have to take that particular element of vector y and compare to all elements of vector z and if it is true return true else if i don't find a greater element in first iteration i,e when elements of vector x are compared to vector y i have to break the loop and return false.

I tried to iterate through all the elements of stackarmies but I don't know how to take the first element of vector one and compare with all the elements of vector, since all the vectors are merged into the last vector.

```
vector<int> stack;

int noofstack, noofoperations, stackno, OperationType;
// Taking the input number of stacks
cin >> noofstack;
vector<vector<int>> stackarmies;
for (int i = 0; i < noofstack; i++)
{
    int stacksize;
    //Since vectors are dynamic and we don't need to declare the size but as per the problem statement I've added it/
    cin >> stacksize;
    for (int k = 0; k < stacksize; k++)
    {
        //Taking the input of all the vectors one by one and then adding all the vectors into one vector

        int armyheight;
         cin>>armyheight;
        stack.push_back(armyheight);
    }
    stackarmies.push_back(stack);
```

## Test cases

**Input 1**

```
2 
3 3 5 4 
3 1 1 2
```

*Resulting `stackarmies`:* `{ {3, 5, 4}, {3, 5, 4, 1, 1, 2} }`

*Desired output*: `False`
We will take first element of vector 1 : 3 and compare with all 
elements of vector 2 , in vector 2 no element is greater than 3.

**Input 2**

```
2
3 1 0 4
3 2 1 3
```

*Resulting `stackarmies`:* `{ {1, 0, 4}, {1, 0, 4, 2, 1, 3} }`

*Desired output*: `True`
We will take first element of vector 1 : 1 and compare with all 
elements of vector 2, in vector 2, the first element is greater than 1, 
so true

**Input 3**

```
2
3 1 9 0
2 0 11
```

*Resulting `stackarmies`:* `{ {1, 9, 0}, {1, 9, 0, 0, 11} }`

*Desired output:* `True`
We will take first element of vector 1 : 1 and compare with all 
elements of vector 2, in vector 2, the last element is greater than 1, 
so true

**Input 4**

```
3
3 0 8 0
3 4 0 11
3 0 9 0
```

*Resulting `stackarmies`:* `{ {0, 8, 0}, {0, 8, 0, 4, 0, 11} , {0, 8, 0, 4, 0, 11, 0, 9, 0} }`

*Desired output:* `True`
We will take the second element of vector 1: 8 and compare with 
all elements of vector 2 , 11 is greater than 8 so we will compare 11 of 
vector 2 with vector , since there are no values greater than 11, so it's 
false

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/ isn't it easier to iterate your vector ?

Comment: @Tom  if I iterate now, it would iterate over the whole vector, whenever I am pickup any element from a vector I don't want to use that vector for comparison, I will compare it to other vectors, forward iteration only.
Its just like picking up one element from first row and comparing with all other elements of second row, if it doesn't match, I will take second element from first vector and again compare it to elements of second row and so on.

Comment: Sorry, but your algorithm is not clear to me - is it so complicated ? What is your goal ? You have unassigned values armyheight, in a stack vector, etc. Maybe problem you are solving by should be easier to understand then algo you are trying to create ;-)

Comment: Haha :-D, I'm sorry for the confusion. I updated it. Can you please check this problem statement and let me know if my approach to this problem is correct or not? 
https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/stacks/basics-of-stacks/practice-problems/algorithm/monk-and-order-of-phoenix/

Comment: Make sure you've discussed and accept the ramifications of reusing `stack` with your [Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah somewhere I feel I shouldn't be creating the same vector again and merging it all into one vector, I think that's why I am having problem iterating.

Comment: Your most-recent edit  moved `stack` to too narrow a scope and it now doesn't exist at `stackarmies.push_back(stack);` Placement of variables is very important so think it through carefully. Draw pictures to help visualize if you aren't sure.

Comment: @user4581301 Sorry for that

Comment: I'm having trouble matching up your problem description to the code sample. Where are "vector x", "vector y", and "vector z"? Where is your attempt to "iterate through all the elements of stackarmies"? When you say "it is true", what does "it" refer to?

Comment: You've identified a difficulty: _"all the vectors are merged into a single vector"_. So don't do that? It's almost like the patient who told a doctor "my face hurts when I punch it", and the doctor replied "stop punching yourself in the face". Why would you do something that causes problems for you?

Comment: @JaMiT So which data structure should I take into?

Comment: @DebabrataPonda Since you have not defined what your requirements are for the input, I have no recommendation for how to do it. Right now, your code for reading input is incomplete (there's a `for` loop without a closing brace), and your expected input/output does not clarify things for me. (I suspect -- but cannot conclude -- that you've merged multiple test cases into a single block of input. The expected output looks strange, but without the code that's supposed to produce it, I can only guess at what you might have intended.) A clearer, more comprehensive problem statement might help.

Comment: @DebabrataPonda Hmm... since you are currently watching this, let me try an edit, and if I misunderstood your intent, you can revert it.

Comment: @JaMiT  Sure! :-)

Comment: @JaMiT Problem Statement https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/stacks/basics-of-stacks/practice-problems/algorithm/monk-and-order-of-phoenix/

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know how to take the first element of vector one and compare with all the elements of vector, since all the vectors are merged into the last vector.

You're getting ahead of yourself. Why do you want all the vectors merged into the last vector? Answer: you don't; that's just what happened. Why did all the vectors merge into the last vector? Answer: because you have a bug in your code that reads the data. Fix that bug instead of spending ten times as much effort trying to handle the malformed data.

That whole spiel about what you intend to do next is nothing more than a distraction that wastes the time of the people from whom you are asking help. Ask for help with the real problem (the loading bug) instead of driving people away with a confusing question that assumes bad data is good.

---

There are several ways to fix the bug. I think the most helpful approach is one that would have avoided the bug in the first place. You try to do too much in a single function. Divide and conquer; when you have a non-trivial sub-step, create a function to handle it. Good programming practices lead to fewer bugs.

Specifically, reading the heights of the fighters in a stack is non-trivial. Delegate that to a helper and reduce the body of your outer `for` loop to a single line.

```
for (int i = 0; i < noofstack; i++)
{
    //* This is non-trivial, so use a helper function.
    stackarmies.push_back(read_fighter_heights());
}
```

This helper function is responsible for reading a line of data, generating a stack (a `vector<int>`) from it, and returning that stack. That covers most of the body of your loop, leaving only the simple task of pushing the returned stack onto your vector of stacks.

Creating this helper function from your existing code is fairly simple. Mostly, just move the body of the loop into an appropriate function definition. In addition, you should notice that `stack` is needed (only) in this function, so also move that variable's declaration into the new function's definition.

```
vector<int> read_fighter_heights()
{
    vector<int> stack;
    int stacksize;
    //Since vectors are dynamic and we don't need to declare the size but as per the problem statement I've added it/
    cin >> stacksize;
    for (int k = 0; k < stacksize; k++)
    {
        //Taking the input of all the vectors one by one and then adding all the vectors into one vector

        int armyheight;
        cin>>armyheight; //* Reading a single integer is trivial, so no need for another function here.
        stack.push_back(armyheight);
    }
    return stack;
}
```

Presto! Problem solved. All you had to do was be more organized.

**Addendum:** The reason this solves the problem is that extra step of moving the declaration of `stack`. In the original code, this variable was declared outside the outer loop, and it was never cleared. The result was that it accumulated values from each line that was read. In this version, the variable is re-initialized before reading each line, so values do not accumulate. You could get the same result by moving the line in the original code, without splitting off a new function. However, splitting off a new function is a good habit to get into, as it almost forces you to declare `stack` at the right level, avoiding the problem in the first place.

Comment: I feel that my code was doing the same thing, as it is pushing all the elements in stack and once it is over, it will push the stacks one by one into the respective indices in stackarmies. I would agree with you that having separate functions is easier for someone to review and the code doesn't look messy.

Comment: Your code was  *almost* doing the same thing. The behavioral difference is that your code would copy each stack's data to the beginning of the stack that follow it, whereas this code does not. Given the input `2 
2 3 5
2 1 1`, your code would populate `stackarmies` with `{ {3, 5}, {3, 5, 1, 1} }`, but my code would populate it with  `{ {3, 5}, {1, 1} }`. This happens because my code resets `stack` to an empty state before reading each line, but yours does not.

Comment: Yes, now I get your point, your approach is better as the stack needs to reinitialized always so performing operations on them based on their indices would be easier. Thanks! BTW, posted an answer, I know it needs to be in terms of time and space complexity, Could you please help me optimize it?

Answer (score 0):

```
bool CompareVectors(vector<vector<int>> st)
{
bool result = true;
for (int k = 0; k < st.size(); k++)
{
    if (k != st.size() - 1)
    {
        if (result)
        {
            for (auto i = st[k].begin(); i != st[k].end(); ++i)
            {
                for (auto j = st[k+1].begin(); j != st[k+1].end(); ++j)
                {
                    if (*i < *j)
                    {
                        result = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = false;
                    }
                }
                if (result)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return result;
}
```